# I added some swift files to my Objective-C project , there is a global constant defined in swift file.How can I use this global constant in OC files?

Tags: objective-c, swift, constants

I define a global constant in swift file and can use it in other swift file. but I failed to use it in OC files.Did i missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24237825/1576134

Answer (score 0):

Global variables / constants defined in Swift don't import to ObjC. It's pretty much just classes and (Int-based) enums that do. See [Swift Type Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID53) in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*.