# Swift property access in ObjC++

Tags: objective-c, swift, class, properties, wrapper

I've got a big problem !

I try to use a Swift property in ObjC++ class but nothing works !

My Swift Class :

```
let wST:CGFloat = 200

@objc class G: NSObject {
    private override init() {}

    class func sizeST() -> CGSize { return CGSize(width: wST, height: 200)}
    // Another test
    static var hST:CGFloat = 200
}
```

In ObjC++ class .h :

```
@class G;
```

In ObjC++ class .mm :

```
#import "PROJECT-Swift.h"
...

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSLog(@"Property : %@", [G sizeST]);

    // With static var
    NSLog(@"Property : %f", G.hST);
}
```

What's wrong ?
Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`G`" in your Objective C code is a class, so what you appear to be trying to do is get a property from a class, not an instance of that class.

You can access a property from an instance (or object) of a class, so `G` needs to be a parameter in your `initWithFrame` or it needs to be its own property in your Obj-C object (e.g. `self.G.hST`).

Another thing you can do is declare your `hST` property as a `class` function instead (e.g. look [at this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237129/how-to-declare-a-constant-in-swift-that-can-be-used-in-objective-c)).   That is:

```
@objc class G: NSObject {

    class func hST() -> CGFloat {
       return 200
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response. It's work !
But I change a little because I want to keep property as static property.

In my class G:

```
static var _hST:CGFloat = 300.0
static func hST() -> CGFloat { return _hST }
```

So I can modify the value inside another Swift class.

In my ObjC class, I use :

```
NSLog(@"hST -> %f", [G hST]);
```

Thanks a lot !