# Using Swift Project (Siren) in an Objective-C iOS Application

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, objective-c-swift-bridge

I am trying to use a popular swift library, [Siren](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren), in an iOS Objective-C application.  I have included the library as a framework using cocoapods, I ran `pod init` and then `pod install` with a podfile like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyObjectiveCApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyObjectiveCApp
  pod 'Siren'

end
```

and I've imported the swift code into the AppDelegate.m file like so:

`#import <Siren/Siren-Swift.h>`

I can now access the `Siren` class, but I can't seem to reference the `shared` static property on the `Siren` class.  I have tried `[Siren shared]` and `Siren.shared` but neither is working.  Here is the first few lines of the `Siren` class:

```
import UIKit

/// The Siren Class.
public final class Siren: NSObject {
    /// Return results or errors obtained from performing a version check with Siren.
    public typealias ResultsHandler = (Result<UpdateResults, KnownError>) -> Void

    /// The Siren singleton. The main point of entry to the Siren library.
    public static let shared = Siren()
```

Is there any documentation or examples of using Siren in an Objective-C iOS application? Is this possible?  I know I could use Harpy, but since it is no longer supported, I was trying to avoid it if possible.  I have researched using Swift in Objective-C code, but I couldn't find anything specifically related to accessing a `static let` property on a class.  I found [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24237825), but it mentions global variables, not static class properties.

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov I tried `@import Siren;`, but I am getting the same errors.  I also tried `#import "Siren-Swift.h"` with the same errors.  If I don't include any of those 3 import statements, the `Siren` class isn't recognized at all, which is expected, but it proves those statements are doing something.

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov Yes I believe so.  I added `@import Siren`, commented out the other import statement, commented out all references to Siren in objective-c, Cleaned the App, Built the App (successfully), added `[Siren shared];` back in, Built the App, and got the error `No known class method for selector 'shared'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't access `shared` property, is because it doesn't get exported to `Siren-Swift.h` header (you can check generated header file).

That's because Siren class is not explicitly marked as `@objc`.
The class itself is exported, because it's subclass of `NSObject`, but the properties are not exported by default. I think we can't solve it on our own.

What we can do is a workaround:

- Let the author know via GitHub issue;
- In meantime you can make your own Swift class-wrapper that direct every call to Siren under the hood, create internal pointer to `Siren.shared`, copy-paste all getters-setters from Siren, proxy calls to real `Siren.shared`;
- Mark your class as `@objc`;
- When (and if) author will solve the issue , you can update Siren, delete your class-wrapper and call Siren directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  I can confirm this works!  I opened a [github issue about this](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren/issues/290).  Hopefully it will turn into a feature of the library.  This is also great advice for any Swift library that is incompatible with Objective-C.

Comment: Maybe the author do not want change it. He says: "Unfortunately, your use case is one that doesn't follow the 80-20 rule. While I understand that many projects exist that are 100% Objective-C, or that have mixed codebases, I don't believe that language is the future of the iOS platform."